# htaccess: RewriteEngine On and AuthUserFile conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite

Let's consider the folder www.mydomain.com/exemple protected with the following .htaccess:

.htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /root/FTPname/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I want to allow the access to the exemple folder only if a user has a specific cookie, or I raise an error (with the following [F] flag). Then I implemented the following code:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName=CookieValue
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

AuthUserFile /root/FTPname/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

The problem is that when i load the exemple folder without the cookie, it goes through the authentification process first...I would like to do raise the error first. Anyone knows?

Comment: OT: `AuthGroupFile /dev/null` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Try "Satisfy any" with a new environment variable. Two techniques are shown here:
[.htaccess basic auth by virtual host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334307/htaccess-basic-auth-by-virtual-host)  One uses SetEnvIf, the other uses a RewriteRule to set the variable. Since SetEnvIf cannot detect cookies, you will need RewriteRule. But I found on my shared hosting platform that RewriteRule could not play with "Satisfy any." If it works for you, it will look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName=CookieValue
RewriteRule .* - [L,E=DENY:1]

AuthUserFile /root/FTPname/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=!DENY
```

See also: [htaccess exclude one url from Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978080/htaccess-exclude-one-url-from-basic-auth)

Watch out that the page you are protecting does not include images, stylesheets, etc., that trigger an authentication request when the page itself does not.